# merge app with applications tag?

Tags: feature-request, retag-request

aren't they about the same thing?

Comment: Did you suggest the synonym?

Comment: nope. how do I do that?

Comment: hmm does that require 2500 rep _on the tag_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge complete.

Don't forget to [vote on synonyms](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms)!

Comment: what's the difference between merges and synonyms? and that link is from another domain

Comment: When a synonym is in effect, it will automatically rename tags to match the "master" tag, but only at the time they're posted. A merge is a manual action. (Link fixed.)